# EditText fails to display inputted text the second time on Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` which is contained in a `ListView`.  Generally this works as it should, as I've set `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` to enable the user to focus the EditText in order to input text.

On devices running Android 2.2, there is a problem that goes like this:

- User taps edit text, enters text
- User dismisses soft keyboard (at this point the entered text disappears)
- User taps edit text again, and attempts to enter text - text does not appear (hint text is visible)
- If the user then dismisses the keyboard and taps the edit text a third time, the text that was entered previously but did not appear will now be visible

This occurs on two different 2.2 devices, but does not occur on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.1, nor does it occur on the emulator.

Here's the XML layout which contains the edit text:

`search_bar.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_section"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/search_bar_height" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar_bg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbarbg" />

    <EditText     <!-- This is the EditText in question -->
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/searchfieldbg"
        android:hint="@string/search_view_hint" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scan_button" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/search_bar_shadow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/search_section"
    android:background="@drawable/shadowtop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the listview which contains the above layout as a row:

`browse_layout.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/main_bg" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/categories_list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
    android:divider="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Removing the EditText row from the adapter and instead adding the EditText as a view using the MergeAdapter from Commonsware seems to have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

no need to change adapter just enter the code shown below:
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);